# How does this query method work?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

```
@Query("MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person) RETURN m,r,a LIMIT {limit}")
Collection<Movie> graph(@Param("limit") int limit);
```

For this query, it's returning "RETURN m, r, a", which is a full subgraph with 3 elements. Then why the return value of 'graph' method is a collection of "Movie" only? Where is the 'r, a' which is also returned.

I am trying to understanding the mechanism behind the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a `@RelationshipEntity` defined in your class path but do not use it when defining `@Relationship`s in the domain classes.

Sample:

```
@NodeEntity
class Pet {
    // ...
}

@NodeEntity
class Person {
    @Relationship(type = "HAS")
    private List<Pet> pets;
    // ...
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS")
class HasRelationship {
    // ...
}
```

If Neo4j OGM, that acts behind the scenes of SDN, finds a relationship type, it looks for `@RelationshipEntity` first and if it finds them, tries to map the returned types back to the `@NodeEntity`. In this case OGM finds `HasRelationship` and wants to map it to the `Person` class. This fails because `Person` does only know of `Pet` and the objects get discarded.

Like my answer [on GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j/issues/25#issuecomment-367982886).

Comment: Thanks for the great example. Meistermeier.